# TypeError:Cannot read property 'getElementById' frameset

Tags: javascript, frame, getelementbyid, frameset

I have a simple code that refreshes the main page each time there is a new version, but it only works in Internet Explorer. In other browsers I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined line 24
```

Here is my code:

```
    <html>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     var num=0;
     var currVersion;
     var started=false;

     function startLoad() {
     var url= "version_telemark.html?"+ (++num);
        window.version.navigate(url);
     }

     function endLoad() {
       if (started) {
         var newVersion = version.document.getElementById("version").value;
         if (newVersion != currVersion) {
           currVersion=newVersion;
           var url  = "telemark.html?"+ (++num);
             window.pane.navigate(url);
         }
       }
     }
     function start() {
        currVersion = version.document.getElementById("version").value;
       started=true;
       setInterval("startLoad()", 200);
     }
    </script>

  <frameset    onload="start()"  cols="40%,100%">
    <frame id="version"   src="version_telemark.html"/>
    <frame id="pane" src="telemark.html" />
  </frameset>

</html>
```

and in my other file I only have that I wish to edit I have:

```
<input id="version" name="version" type="textbox" value="700">
```

and my other file that has the *design* just has tables but we wont need to add anything there.

Comment: Just FWIW, `frameset` is no longer part of the HTML specification.

Comment: Do you see any other errors when you run your app with a Developer Tools console open? (You might be prevented from accessing frame document for security reasons.)

Comment: On chrome it sends me this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined

Comment: Well, the error you're getting means that `version.document` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Your code is relying on the automatic global that browsers create for elements that have `id`s on them, by using `version` as a global variable without declaring or initializing it. Perhaps for some reason, the automatic global isn't working on browsers other than IE. I don't like to rely on them anyway, it's too easy to shadow them, so I suggest getting the element on purpose by adding this near the top of your script:

   ```
   var version = document.getElementById("version");
   ```

   But your comment on the question suggests that it's not this, but #2 below:
2. You may need `vesrion.contentDocument` rather than `version.document` in your `currVersion = version.document.getElementById("version").value;` and similar lines; perhaps JavaScript's curiously-powerful `||` operator:

   ```
   var versionDoc = version.document || version.contentDocument;
   // ...and then
   currVersion = versionDoc.getElementById("version").value;
   // ...and so on
   ```

---

Side note: Just to keep yourself and whoever has to maintain the code after you sane, I'd also suggest different `id` values for the `version` `frame` and the `version` `input` inside it.

Comment: after that it showed me a new error: Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Comment: @HenriqueAlves: That means you're doing this with a local file rather than something served from a web server (in your address bar, the URL starts with `file://`). Some browsers, like Chrome, apply the Same Origin Policy to local resources, and enforce it as though all local resources were from different origins (thereby disallowing access). If you load it from a web server (`localhost`, for instance, for development purposes), the origins will match and that won't happen. It's always best to test web stuff via a web server, not with `file:///` URLs.

Comment: i feel soo bad about all this but now it says another erro :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined on line 10

Comment: @HenriqueAlves: You probably need `contentWindow` for that bit: `window.pane.contentWindow.navigate(url);`

Comment: @HenriqueAlves: Well, as with `version`, that code is relying on an automatic global. I'd switch it over to `getElementById` as well. There's nothing for it but to walk through with the debugger built into your browser, inspect the objects as your code is running, etc., etc. Good luck,

Comment: guess that i will have to find a better way, well we tried